# Visual Studio won't stop displaying "Source not found" window for third party dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging an app that makes use of `System.Reactive.dll`.  I am not sure how it happened but all of a sudden while debugging VS will stop and show a "Source not found" window for basically anything from `System.Reactive.dll`.  For example:

> Subject.cs not found

> You need to find Subject.cs to view the source code for the current call stack frame.

This happens for `Merge, RefCount, TakeUntil, Select`, etc.

**"Enable Just My Code"** is checked in the debug options.  I am not trying to step into any of these reactive methods (I am just hitting F10 while debugging).

How can I disable this?  It is making debugging the app impossible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your description, If “Enable Just My Code” doesn’t work you can try the following methods:

1. check Enable source server support under Tools > Options > Debugging > General
   [image]
2. Reset all settings under Tools > Import and Export Settings
   [image]

Comment: Option two did the trick for me.  After resetting the settings things returned to normal.

Comment: Well, even if this works, this is really an annoying solution, because it resets every non related setting as well. Would be good to know, which actual setting would fix this.

Comment: Well here is a slightly better solution: First export your current settings. Then Reset all settings. Afterwards Import your exported settings, but unselect "Options -> Debugging". This way everything else is kept.